# php artisan test ignore phpunit.xml

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, pest

When I run my tests with Phpstorm everthing works as expected and the connection switches to `mysql_test`. But when I run `php artisan test` manually the connection wont switch and remain `mysql`.

##### `phpunit.xml file`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./Modules/**/Tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./Modules/**/Tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql_test"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql_test"/>
        <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">./Modules</directory>
        </include>
    </source>
</phpunit>
```

##### One of my test files

```
class BannerTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithFaker;

    private static $authUser;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        // first include all the normal setUp operations
        parent::setUp();
        self::$authUser = Operator::factory()->create();
        $this->app->make(\Spatie\Permission\PermissionRegistrar::class)->registerPermissions();
    }

    public function giveBannerPermission()
    {
        $operator = self::$authUser;
        $this->be(self::$authUser);
        $operator->assignRole('admin');
        $role = Role::findByName('admin');
        $role->givePermissionTo('bannerAdd');
    }

    public function banner_requires_status()
    {
        $this->giveBannerPermission();
        $banner = Banner::factory()->raw(['title' => NULL]);

        $this->post(route('banner.store'), $banner)->assertSessionHasErrors('title');
    }
}
```

i've also tried `php artisan optimize:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` before running test but nothing changes.

Comment: Have you tried running `php artisan config:clear` before running `php artisan test`?

Comment: @Remul yes i tried

Comment: Just to say, you should create an `.env.testing` file to handle these kind of environment variables. It's a proper way.

Comment: Maybe it is a problem, that you have a duplicate <env name="DB_CONNECTION">-Tag.

Comment: @Henning no its not :( it's just a dummy typo. the original file in my project is not duplicated

Comment: @VincentDecaux i even tried with a separate env and run the PHP artisan test --env=testing command but nothing changed :(

Comment: you must not have your config cached, else it will always use the cached config. I know you already said that you run `php artisan config:clear`, but do it again and run it again, you must not have the config cached

Answer (score 3):

you need to create another .env called ".env.testing"
then update your phpunit.xml like this:

```
<php>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
    <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
</php>
```

your .env.testing:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=avo-test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

this should fix your problem.